# Add a random change in color for every iteration

Tags: javascript, random

I am writing a quiz sort of game and I want the background to change every time there is a new question. Could someone help me with either how to code this or ideally the code? (I haven't copied the array in as it links to a CSV.

Here is my current code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 18) + 1);
    var stringGuess = prompt(questions[number])
    if (stringGuess == answers[number]) {
        alert("YOU GOT IT RIGHT!! THE ANSWER IS " + answers[number])
    } else if (stringGuess > answers[number]) {
        alert("Too high. The answer is " + answers[number]);
    } else {
        alert("Too low. The answer is " + answers[number]);
    }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't type question above, StackOverflow won't allow you to write the word in a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a random colour you could set a random RGB value using the function below. To set css background-color on an element you can use element.style.backgroundColour = colour;

```
function randomRGB(){
  return `rgb(${Math.floor(Math.random()*256)},${Math.floor(Math.random()*256)},${Math.floor(Math.random()*256)})`;
}
function setColour(element, colour){
  element.style.backgroundColour = colour;
}
```

Therefore, use this whenever you need to set a random background colour:
`setColour(document.getElementById("my-background-element"), randomRGB());`

remembering to change "my-background-element" to the id of the background element you have.